# Collision Detection using 2D Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have some code that works pretty well, but could someone explain how this works to prevent collision in a video game?  What does this code actually mean?

```
var checkCollision = function (bugs) {
   if(player.y + 131 >= bugs.y + 90
      && player.x + 25 <= bugs.x + 88
      && player.y + 73 <= bugs.y + 135
      && player.x + 76 >= bugs.x + 11) {
          console.log('YOU LOSE!');
      }
}
```

Comment: Obviously it's comparing the x/y coordinates of the player and bugs objects on the 2D plane and trying to see if they overlap or touch. But w/out any more context, it's hard to say what's going on. It would make sense if the numbers that are added to each x/y coordinate were similar (representing the width/height of the player/bug objects). But there's seemingly no pattern to that ... maybe you should add more code and/or a screen shot of the player/bug collision.

Answer (score 3):

This is a common collision detection approach. Firstly each object, that being the `player` and the `bug`, have their position along with a `width` and `height` to them:

[image]

Now if we look at one of the conditions of the form: `player.x + A >= bugs.x + B` we have a line:

[image]

Place four lines together and you get a collision box:

Here is how collisions tend to look like:

```
if (player.x < bug.x + bug.width       // Player X is to the left of the bug's right
&& player.x + player.width > bug.x     // Player X is the to right of the bug's left
&& player.y < bug.y + bug.height       // Player Y is above the bottom of the bug
&& player.height + player.y > bug.y) { // Player Y is below the top of the bug
    // found a collision
}
```

This is an overlap between the `player` and the `bug`:

[image]

Comment: This really helped me to rewrite the code based on this logic. It works.   But how is there a collision if all of these statements are true?  If the player is to the left, right, top, or bottom of bug then there wouldn't be a collision would there?  Following the line diagram, It seems that you would have a true, false, false true on the x axis and a true, false, false true on the y coordinates.

Comment: @Ginger22 There are two pairs of checks, one for the `x-axis` and one for the `y-axis`. The first 2 for the `x` makes two parallel lines that means if the players `x` is within the boundary of the bug's `x`. But then it could be anywhere on the `y-axis`. The next two conditions do the same things as the `x` but on they `y-axis`, to ensure that the player's `y` is within the boundary of the bug's `y`.